# Session Manager using Shared Pref

Tags: java, android, session, sharedpreferences

I'm using shared preference to store user data, and in my start screen, I want to check whether username has already logged in or not, when user is still not logged out yet it will redirect to UserView.java when the application starts, otherwise it will go to LoginActivity.java

I've used these tutorial as my references :
[Android Hive Tutorial Shared Pref](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/), and 
[Android example tutorial Shared Pref](http://androidexample.com/Android_Session_Management_Using_SharedPreferences_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=127&aaid=147)..

but when I exit my activity without logging out, next time I open my application it's status is logged out (its like the session has ended although I have not logged out yet from my application),,

What should I do to fix this thing, so whenever I exit my application (without logging out) my data is still there in shared pref and will be redirected to UserView.java, Am i making any mistakes with my codes?

These are my code:

userSessionManager.java

```
package com.thesis.teamizer;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;

public class userSessionManager {

// Shared Preferences Reference
SharedPreferences CurrentSession;

// Editor Reference for Editing Shared Preferences
Editor editor;

// Context Reference
Context _context;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharef Preferences Name
public static String PrefName = "MyUsername";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "IsUserLoggedIn";

// User name (make variable public to access from outside)
public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";

// Constructor
public userSessionManager(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
    CurrentSession = _context.getSharedPreferences(PrefName, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = CurrentSession.edit();
}

public void createUserLogin(String username) {

    // User has already login
    editor.putBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing username in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);

    // Editor ready to execute the previous codes
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean checkLogin() {
    // Check login status. If the user is not logged in
    if (!this.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// Read session using hashmap
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {

    // Use hashmap to store user credentials
    HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // user name
    user.put(KEY_USERNAME, CurrentSession.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));

    // return user
    return user;
}

public void logOut() {
    // clearing all data from Shared pref
    editor.remove(KEY_USERNAME);
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
}

// Will check if the user is Login or not by getting the boolean of
// IS_USER_LOGIN from CurrentSession(pref)
private boolean isUserLoggedIn() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return CurrentSession.getBoolean(IS_USER_LOGIN, false);
}
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.thesis.teamizer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener     {

private EditText etUsername;
private EditText etPassword;
private Button bLogin, bRegis, bAdmin;
userSessionManager session;
String loginUrl;
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
String Username;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    Declaration();

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    bRegis.setOnClickListener(this);
    bAdmin.setOnClickListener(this);

    if (session.checkLogin()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.USERVIEW");
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void Declaration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etLoginPassword);
    bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
    bRegis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
    bAdmin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdminadmin);
    session = new userSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
    Username = user.get(userSessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    myIP ip = new myIP();
    String myIp = ip.getIp();
    String thisPhp = "doLogin.php";
    loginUrl = myIp + thisPhp;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bLogin:
        new AttemptLogin().execute();

        break;

    case R.id.bRegister:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.REGISTRATIONACTIVITY");
        startActivity(i);

        break;

    }
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(loginUrl, "POST",
                    params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                String currentLoginUsername = username;
                session.createUserLogin(currentLoginUsername);
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.USERVIEW");
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                String sukses = "Sukses login";
                return sukses;
            } else if (success == 0) {
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), file_url,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}

}
```

UserView.java

```
package com.thesis.teamizer;

import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserView extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

public Button createGr, viewGr, createAn, viewAn, notification, logout,
        calendar, createEvent, myEvent, createTask, myTask;
public String Username;
userSessionManager session;
Intent i;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_view);
    sessionAndDeclaration();
    createGr.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewGr.setOnClickListener(this);
    createAn.setOnClickListener(this);
    viewAn.setOnClickListener(this);
    notification.setOnClickListener(this);
    logout.setOnClickListener(this);
    createEvent.setOnClickListener(this);
    calendar.setOnClickListener(this);
    myEvent.setOnClickListener(this);
    createTask.setOnClickListener(this);
    myTask.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void sessionAndDeclaration() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    session = new userSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();

    // get name
    Username = user.get(userSessionManager.KEY_USERNAME);
    TextView a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvUserVUsername);
    a.setText(Username);
    createGr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateGroup);
    viewGr = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewMyGroup);
    createAn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateAnnouncement);
    viewAn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewMyAnnouncement);
    notification = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bNotification);
    logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDoLogout);
    calendar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGoToMyCalendar);
    createEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCreateEvent);
    myEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGoToMyEvent);
    createTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGoToCreateTask);
    myTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGoToMyTask);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bCreateGroup:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.CREATEGROUPACTIVITY");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bViewMyGroup:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.MYGROUPACTIVITY");
        startActivity(i);

        break;

    case R.id.bCreateAnnouncement:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.CREATEANNOUNCEMENTACTIVITY");
        startActivity(i);

        break;

    case R.id.bViewMyAnnouncement:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.VIEWALLANNOUNCEMENT");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bNotification:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.NOTIFICATION");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bDoLogout:
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to Logout?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                finish();
                                session.logOut();
                                Intent i = new Intent(
                                        "com.thesis.teamizer.LOGINACTIVITY");

                                // Closing all the Activities
                                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                                // Add new Flag to start new Activity
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                                // Staring Login Activity
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

        break;

    case R.id.bGoToMyCalendar:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.VIEWCALENDAR");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bCreateEvent:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.CREATEEVENT");
        startActivity(i);

        break;

    case R.id.bGoToMyEvent:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.MYEVENT");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bGoToCreateTask:
        i= new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.CREATETASK");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case R.id.bGoToMyTask:
        i = new Intent("com.thesis.teamizer.MYTASK");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Where do you call createUserLogin() ? In code provided I did not found it. Has to work, if you update prefs when user logeed in/out and look in onStart method of your first Activity if user is logged in

Comment: Hi @AntonKizema ,, thank you for your response,, I intentionally removed some part of the code so it would make it easier to see my code, but it makes the createUserLogin removed as well, I've edited my full code above.. Sorry

Comment: shered pref save file as .xml and you can use unique id or token by which you allow to access data.